# Django Channels 2.0 and Daphne: serving static and media files

Tags: django, django-channels, daphne

I've searched some time, but couldn't find any tutorial on how to serve static *and* user uploaded (/media/) files in conjunction with Daphne. I've read that Apache doesn't support ASGI, that it may be possible to use Nginx, but nothing specific.

I've also tried [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) (which only supports static files) and [dj-static](https://github.com/heroku-python/dj-static) (which only supports WSGI). I'd like not to use external CDNs, for privacy reasons.

Can you provide any hints on possible setups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In production it is better to let nginx/apache to serve static/media files. If you are using nginx, add this to your config.

```
location /static {
    alias {{ project_root }}/static;
}

location /media {
    alias {{ project_root }}/media;
}
```

Neither apache nor nginx support ASGI. You have to use daphne or uvicorn which will run behind nginx/apache to support ASGI. I have also written an article  [on django channels deployment](https://avilpage.com/2018/05/deploying-scaling-django-channels.html), if you need more details.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've ended up using, thank you very much! I wish there was a fork of rednoise that supported ASGI (because this would enable one to limit specific media file access to logged in users etc.)